# Not able to unset git user.name

Tags: git, github

I am doing my project and ran into a weird error of git. I clone a private project of a company named X by setting the user.name by following these commands :

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
```

and then :-

```
git config --global --add user.name <whatever>
```

was able to clone the project. After this when I tried to push to my git profile I was unable to do that. It gave me the below error :-

```
Vikass-MacBook-Air% git push          
remote: Permission to vikkyconer/coursera-test.git denied to X.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vikkyconer/coursera-test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

After normal googling I found and understood that I have to reset again my user.name.

I ran the above two commands again but I was unsuccessful to push to my branch. I am obviously able to clone the project and also able to take the pull of the project but not able to run git push.

I reset my global, local and system's git user.

After unset all users below command confirms me that no present user is there.

```
git config -l
```

I am still not able to do git push. Please help me if someone out there also faced the above error.

Comment: so `git config --global user.name <whatever>` doesn't work?

Comment: nope.. I tried it couple of times.. it's quite frustrating.. thinking of reinstalling git.. maybe that could help.. :(

Comment: how about `git config --local user.name <whatever>` ?

Comment: nope.. not even git config --system --get-all user.name .. actually git config -l is not showing the name X but still it's giving me the error.

Comment: when you type `git config --local user.name` or `git config --global user.name` what's the output?

Comment: Your `user.name` is *ignored* when doing https and ssh authentication.  On MacOS, https authentication uses the osx-credentials-helper.  See https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: It shows me my user name not X

Comment: Thanks @torek your help solved my problem.. 
helped a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

- Edit `~/.gitconfig` file in your home folder. This is where all `--global` settings are saved.

Or You can do this

- `git config --global --replace-all user.name "user_name"`

Comment: Tried this also... no success... ~/.gitconfig does not have the name X it has my username

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you'd normally do on a private repository

1. You'd get yourself signed-up with Git Hub
2. On Git Hub, navigate to main page of the repository
3. Find and click *Settings*
4. Find and click *Collaborators*
5. Type in collaborators name
6. Select the collaborator from the drop down list
7. Click add collaborator
8. The user will receive an email collaboration request.
9. Accept it and done

[Reference](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/)

Comment: Thanks for your time but I do not want to add company user X as a collaborator. I want to push as my own personal user.

Comment: Is this your private repository? Whatever you specify as your `user.name` doesn't really have an effect on your ability to push or pull from the private repository. What is important is having the correct level of authorization assigned to you as the user of Git Hub.